# Disabling a lowest value from dropdown

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a dropdown list array which is shown in my UI How can I disable all highest elements in array and I want to enable only the lowest value in array

```html
<select class="select-option" name="tier" required [ngModel]="tierDropDown">
    <option value="select Tier" selected>Select Tier</option>
    <option class="option" *ngFor="let tier of tierList" let i="index" value="{{tier}}" [disabled]="arr">
        {{ tier }}
    </option>
</select>
```

**.TS file**:

```js
tierList = ["Tier1", "Tier2", "Tier3", "Tier4", "Tier5"]
this.arr = [];
let min = this.tierList;
this.arr = min.sort();
this.arr.splice(this.arr[0], 1);
console.log(this.arr);
this.arr.splice(this.arr[0], 1);
console.log(this.arr);
```

this will return splicing lower element and all higher elements so I am binding that value in `[disabled]` property in HTML file but the result is all my dropdown values are disabled

Comment: When you say lowest value in the dropdown, do you mean you want to disable the last value in your dropdown?

Comment: No I want to disable all highest values in dropdown for example arr =[1,2,3,4,5] i want to disable [2,3,4,5]

Comment: Check out my answer then, there is an easier way to do this without the need for any code in the component for disabling

Answer (score 1):

You can store the lowest value from array in a local variable and then use for that variable for `[disabled]` attribute:

HTML Code:

```
<select class="select-option" name="tier" required [ngModel]="tierDropDown">
 <option value="select Tier" selected>Select Tier</option>
 <option class="option" *ngFor="let tier of tierList" let i="index" value="{{tier}}" [disabled]="tier != LowestValue">
   {{ tier }}
 </option>
</select>
```

TS:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'select-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['select-overview-example.css'],
})
export class SelectOverviewExample {
  tierList = ["Tier1", "Tier5", "Tier3", "Tier4", "Tier2"]
  LowestValue: any;
  constructor() {
    this.LowestValue = this.tierList.sort()[0];
  }
}
```

[`Working_Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vfktgp)

Comment: Still think its bettet with an object. Using the display name as option value never works in the long run. The value needs to be an identifier. Check my answer. By preparing the model you html will be simpler

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a much easier way to do this than the answers provided here. `ngFor` has exported values that can be aliased to local variables (Source: [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables)). We can use the `first` local variable to disable all elements but the `first` in the dropdown.

As per the docs

> `first: boolean`: True when the item is the first item in the iterable.

With this in mind, we can disable every value that is not the `first` item in the dropdown using `[disabled]="!first"`

Here's how your HTML will now look

```html
<select class="select-option" name="tier" required [ngModel]="tierDropDown">
    <option value="select Tier" selected>Select Tier</option>
    <option class="option" *ngFor="let tier of tierList; let first = first" value="{{tier}}" [disabled]="!first">
        {{ tier }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Then in your component just sort `tierList`.

Comment: Then just sort `tierList` in the component. `ngFor` will disable all values except the `first` after that.

Comment: Sure, added it to my answer 

Answer (score 0):

`[disabled]` should bind to a *boolean*. Now you are binding it to an array arr. So it Will always be true. The arr exists. I don’t understand completely what you want to do but if you add en object to your tierList you could calculate an property isDisabled for every element and bind that to the disabled.

Ex: `{name:tier1,disabled:true}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following answer , 

Your **html file**

```
<select class="select-option" name="tier" required >
   <option value="select Tier" selected>Select Tier</option>
   <option  class="option" [disabled]="arr" *ngIf="arr">
      {{arr}}
   </option>
   <option  class="option" *ngFor="let tier of tierList" let i="index" value="{{tier}}" >
    {{ tier }}
   </option>
</select>
```

In **.ts** file ,

```
tierList =["Tier1","Tier2","Tier3","Tier4","Tier5"];
arr = [];
let min = this.tierList;
this.arr = min.sort();

this.arr.splice(this.arr[0], 1);
this.arr = this.arr.splice(this.arr[0], 1);
this.arr = this.arr[0]
console.log(this.arr[0]);
console.log(this.tierList);
```

This answer will work for you.